# Is it possible to set background for a row inside a css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to give background to a full row inside a css grid?
[image: Full width background for grid rows]

If i give background-color to the child elements of the grid it will looks like this
[image: not full size colored boxes]

Is there any solution for this expect making every child element "stretch" size and using them as a flexbox to center the content?

Comment: Why not use flexbox instead? This layout seems to benefit from Flexbox more that CSS Grid

Comment: can you show us you code too please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to have the grid elements stretch to fill the space. If you don't want to do that, you will need to wrap the grid elements in other elements that *do* stretch if you want to have an adaptive background.

Comment: Actually it's not necessary to *wrap* the elements. Additional elements can be *layered* which cover the same whole row.